# retrieving the value of Toggle Switch from Settings.bundle with Swift 5

Tags: swift, toggle

[image]

```
let sfx : Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: SettingsBundleKeys.SFX)
```

Whenever the code runs. the value being retrieved is always false. As you can see in the image, the default value is YES (on application first install, it should be true until the user changes it to NO)

```
struct SettingsBundleKeys {
    static let Reset = "RESET_APP_KEY"
    static let Music = "MUSIC_PREFERENCE"
    static let SFX = "SFX_PREFERENCE"
    static let BuildVersionKey = "build_preference"
    static let AppVersionKey = "version_preference"
}
```

Comment: What's the value of SettingsBundleKeys.SFX?

Comment: Thats just a struct that holds the values of my Identifiers in my Root.plist

Comment: Do you call UserDefault's registerDefaults from application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: I didnt realize that it was still needed with Swift. I used to do that with ObjC.
I did call it within application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: UserDefaults.standard.register

do I need to register my Model with default values explicitly defined? I thought the entire point of having Default Value in the plist was to save some time so we didnt have to do this?

Comment: Docs (registerDefaults) seem to be saying: "you need to call this method each time your application starts. You can place a plist file in the application's Resources directory and call register(defaults:) with the contents that you read in from that file"

Comment: @Shadowrun thanks. Can you put something as an answer so I can give you credit and anyone else who may have a similar question can see your response as an accepted answer? there are a lot of outdated answers and seeing a current one is always helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a settings bundle:

The "default value"s in the settings bundle are only used by the iOS Settings app and never by your app.
The "default value for a toggle switch" is saying show the toggle  as ON if there is no userDefault (either `YES` or `NO`) set yet.

You need to do something in your own app so that if the user hasn't chosen a default value for this key you treat it also as YES so that it matches the 'default default value' in the settings bundle.

One possibility would be that instead of

```
let sfx: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: SettingsBundleKeys.SFX)
```

you could use objectForKey, which would return nil, and then you would know to use the 'default default' and could behave as if `YES` has been set as the value. (This kind of thing could be achieved using a property wrapper on user defaults) but what Apple say is:

Call UserDefault's registerDefaults from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

That way your app and the settings app are in sync with respect to the 'default defaults' - values to be used for keys for which no user default has been registered - and then `bool(forKey: SettingsBundleKeys.SFX)` would return `YES` even if no user default has yet been set for the `SFX` key